# Responsive HTML Design - Resizing the whole content of the page

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive

I was wondering what can we do to make the resize of the page keeping every proportion on it ?

I’ll explain a little bit myself : Let’s say I have a red square that takes my whole page and a green square that is centered on the page (imagine its dimension being half of the full page)

When I resize my page, I want to still have a whole red square and half of a centered green square (If that’s not clear, tell me I will try to explain it better)

Does anyone have an idea please?

I have already tried aspect-ratio but it didn’t work

Comment: It would help us if you could give an example of what you have tried. And by 'page' do you mean the viewport? In which case have you tried using the viewport units (vw/vh/vmin etc)?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #container {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #red-square {
      background-color: red;
      width: 100%;
      aspect-ratio: 1/1; 
    }

    #green-square {
      background-color: green;
      width: 50%;
      max-width: 50vh; 
      aspect-ratio: 1/1; 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="red-square"></div>
    <div id="green-square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this code, if you want the `green square` to be red then add display:flex to `container` id